# Change Child's component parameters in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

My current structure is this:

```
public partial class MyComponentBase<T> : ComponentBase
{
   [Parameter]
   public int SelectedId {get;set;}

   public T Data{get;set;}
}

public class Dto1
{
   public int Property1{get;set;}
   public string Property2{get;set;}
}

public class Dto2 : Dto1
{
   public string Property3{get;set;}
}

//razor.cs file
public partial class MyChildBaseComponent<T> : MyComponentBase<T> where T:Dto1
{
    @typeparam T

    <MudNumericField @bind-Value="Data.Property1"  Variant="Variant.Outlined"/>
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="Data.Property2"  Variant="Variant.Outlined"/>
}

//cs.file
public partial class MyChildBaseComponent<T> : MyComponentBase<T> where T:Dto1
{
   [Parameter]
   public Service<T> DbService{get;set;}
}

public partial class MyChildDerivedComponent : MyChildComponentBase<Dto2>
{
   //to get the base template
   @code{
     base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
  }

  <MudTextField @bind-Value="Data.Property3"  Variant="Variant.Outlined"/>
}

//this is the .cs part
public partial class MyChildComponent : MyComponentBase<Dto1>
{
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
      //initialize data from database
      Data= await DbService.GetData(SelectedId);
   }
}

//this is the parent component
public partial class MyParentComponent : ComponentBase
{
    @inject Service<Dto2> DbService


    <MyChildDerivedComponent @ref="myChild" SelectedId="SelectedId" DbService="DbService"/>
    <MudButton OnClick="SaveInDatabase" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">
       Save
    </MudButton>


    @code{
      [Parameter]
      public int SelectedId {get;set;}

      private async Task SaveInDatabase()
      {
          //I need to change some child's Data parameters properties
          Data.Property3="Test";
          //save in db, this is an example
          await DbService.Insert(Data);
      }
 }
```

}

I have read that using @ref is not the correct way to change component's parameter and this thing should be avoided after the first parameter initialization and outside the owner component.

My questions are several:

-To get the base template is correct to use the BuildRenderTree method or is better to use the RenderFragment type or any better way?

- Should in the parent component be created a local T Data property and passed to the child component or is correct like I do now? The method that I am using already works and I don't see any warning, with the cascading parameters the warning of changing parameter's value is the same or not?
  Is good to modify component 's property from the parent? There is another way instead of @ref?
- My current case require that the Data property is initialized from the child component and in the parent some properties are changed and finally this property will be saved to db, this because i have a base component that will be the same for every parent and only change the type requiring to pass the service directly injected in the parent.

-Is the component inheritance done correctly in this way?

-I don't understand the difference between changing the parameter with @ref directly to the proprerty and doing two way binding with a parameter , maybe I don't understand because in my case i have a reference type parameter and side effects can't be seen, I am wrong?

Sorry for my english.
I hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're wondering about the edits, I started to try and reformat you code, but gave up.

Answer (score 1):

This looks contrived and very convoluted.  It's hard to discern your real intent, so I can only guess and offer some generic advice.

You need to get your data and it's management out of your components.

One way to do this is create a presentation layer object:

```cs
public class MyPresenter<T>
{
    public T? Item {get; private set} = default(T);

    public async Task LoadAsync(Guid id)
    {
        // populate T
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync(Guid id)
    {
        // save T
    }
}
```

In your top level form you create and cascade it.

```cs
@if(this.Presenter is not null)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="this.Presenter">

    //...
    <CascadingValue>
}
@code {
    private readonly MyPresenter<MyDataClass> Presenter = new();

    protected override Task OnInitialisedAsync()
    {
        await Presenter.LoadAsync(); 
    }
}
```

Any components can then consume it:

```cs
    //...
}
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private MyPresenter<MyDataClass> Presenter {get; set;}
}
```

To answer your questions:

Using `BuildRenderTree` method is OK. Though building a deep inheritance structure of components with content is not normally a good idea and can be very difficult for anyone other than you to understand.

> I don't understand the difference between changing the parameter with @ref directly to the property and doing two way binding with a parameter , maybe I don't understand because in my case I have a reference type parameter and side effects can't be seen, I am wrong?

Parameter values are applied from the parent to the child every time the parent is rendered and the renderer detects a change in one of the parameters.

Any manual changes you make:

1. Will be overridden by the incoming value from a parent render event.
2. Will not be applied to the UI until the component is rendered.

You're getting away with it because, as you say, you're just passing references.  Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.

Components are created, managed and destroyed by the Renderer.

When your solution needs to break the rules, it normally means you've got the design wrong.

Comment: What should be the correct way instead of buildredertree to create an component inheritance template?

Comment: My final goal is to have base component with a base template that will be used in all parents, the only thing that change is the type passed by the parent, the item retrieved from database one common part will be visualized in base component and every derived class will add edit field and graphic component to interact with added properties and maintain always the base component functionality, the base component would have a generic constraint on base class, those derived classes will be utilized in parent component that would modify the T item and send to the db.

Comment: One solution from my side would be to not make the T Item property a component but only a parameter but this would be accessible only with @ref and you just explained that is not good, the alternative way would be to make it a cascading parameter, but this T item should be initiated from the child and I don't know if cascading parameters should be initialized from the child or is a bad practice, and parameter shouldn't not be changed directly from the owner so the edit texts in the child is not a good practice or I am wrong? Sorry for many questions but I don't know how to differently.

Comment: If a make the T Item a a cascading parameters and create a local instance in parent getting the data from db in parent an passing it to the child that will be used for all input fields this would be considered bad anyway?

Comment: `ComponentBase` isn't designed for templating so you probably need to design your own component.  [Polite] At the moment there's a big gap between what you want to build and your knowledge in how to construct it.  An SO question and answer is not going to bridge that gap.  You need to experiment, make your mistakes and learn.  There's no short cut to acquire that knowledge.